# Issue with Backbone fragment version 1.2.3

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Currently I updated the newer version of backbone. In my places of my project I have used
"`Backbone.history.fragment`", in the previous version I use to get the result as 
"`demoPage`"

But now it is returning the entire URL except domain like
"`demoPage?id=123&page=test`"

Instead of using split or indexOf, is there a way to get the fragmented value from the newer version in backbone

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking in `Backbone.history.location`

This one might be what you're looking for `Backbone.history.location.pathname`